# Rails - Passing nested params from a form into a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails Strong params to help with allowing nested input params and seem to be having issues with it. I'm following the rails documentation for `accepts_nested_attributes_for` [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), but had little luck with it as my database relationships are a little more complicated. Would highly appreciate the assistance of the rails community here in getting my inputs passed into the backend.

My Database relationships:

Ticket Model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device, polymorphic: true
end
```

Device Model:

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets, as: :device
  has_many :addresses, foreign_key: 'device_id'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

and

Address Model:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device
end
```

With these relationships in place, I have a form that creates a ticket. The form should allow a list of `address` inputs to be specified on the form which are used to create the `Address` objects and the list of `addresses` are further associated to the `Device` itself.

Here's how I am passing these nested input params during the `Ticket` creation:

Ticket controller:

```
def create
  ticket = Ticket::Creator.call(ticket_params: ticket_params)
  redirect_to path(ticket)
end

private

def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(
    {
      device: %i[#device_params],
      address_attributes: %i[name] # name is input by the user.
    }
  )
end
```

With the way I have things setup now, the controller should first create a Ticket, followed by creation of a `Device` and a list of `Address` objects that are related to the `Device`. But I do not seem to be able to read the `address_attributes` on the form.

Here's how I have been grabbing them on the form:

```
name: 'ticket[device][addresses][][name]'
```

is there something I am doing wrong here? Let me know if there is more info I can provide here.

Comment: A few hints (that may not solve your problem) : you are creating three levels of objects in your form : ticket, device and addresses. But you have only one model having `accept_nested_attributes` helper. It seems there should be one more. Also what is strange is that a ticket is a child of device. Then we could think that device will exist before there is any ticket created. Though (if I understand well) your form create the ticket, the device and the addresses altogether. To me there is something not great here.

Comment: Yes @hashrocket.

Answer (score 0):

You should use accept_nested_attributes like this:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :device, polymorphic: true
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :device
end 

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets, as: :device
  has_many :addresses, foreign_key: 'device_id'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :device
end
```

With that model setup you can use strong params with nesting like this in your TicketController:

```
def create
  ticket = Ticket.create(ticket_params)
  redirect_to path(ticket)
end

private

def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(
      device_attributes: [
          addresses_attributes: [:name]
      ]          
  )
end
```

Keep in mind that for creating multiple addresses you would need to pass the following addresses_attributes: `ticket[device_attributes][addresses_attributes][][name]`.

I would suggest that you overthink your polymorphic relation. Because of that relation you would need to pass a `device_type` in your `ticket_params`